# Flumotion playlist

Tags: video-streaming

I am trying to set up a [Flumotion](http://www.flumotion.net/) server. The documents are very partial and I cannot find how to set up a playlist?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a playlist-producer and configure the playlist location from the flumotion admin.

Btw, the documentation is not so partial, but it's missing a section on playlist indeed: http://www.flumotion.net/doc/flumotion/manual/en/trunk/html/